# Set an instant velocity on Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo7, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on Gazebo 7 with ROS kinetic.
So, here is my problem, I have that code function :

```
    void SetVelocity(const double &_vel)
    {   
        this->model->GetJointController()->SetVelocityTarget(this->joint->GetScopedName(), _vel);
    }
```

It's used to set a velocity to my pioneer, it's working pretty well but I want the velocity to be instant.
For exemple, when I set it to a velocity of 30 and then a velocity of 0, it will take so many time to stop. What are the solutions ? Here is the rest of the code :

```
        this->model = _model; 
        this->joint = _model->GetJoints()[0];
        this->pid = common::PID(0.1, 0, 0, 1000, -1000, 1000, -1000);
        this->model->GetJointController()->SetVelocityPID(this->joint->GetScopedName(), this->pid);
```

Thank in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258684/set-an-instant-velocity-on-gazebo/) by [shenki](https://answers.ros.org/users/29921/shenki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For the moment I found that, it's working but it's not that good...

```
    public: void SetVelocity(const double &_vel)
    {
        double __vel = _vel;
        if(__vel>30)__vel=30;
        this->joint->SetDamping(0,old_value/10);
        this->joint->Update();
        this->model->GetJointController()->SetVelocityTarget(this->joint->GetScopedName(), __vel);
        old_value = __vel;
    }
```

This is stupid, so if someone has better, i'll take it, thank you !

---

Originally posted by [shenki](https://answers.ros.org/users/29921/shenki/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0